# django-cms language_chooser in that language

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, django-cms

A typical language_chooser from multilingual Django-CMS framework, displays languages like this:

```
<a href="{% page_language_url language.0 %}">{% trans language.1 %}</a>

English German Dutch
```

How should this snippet be changed, to translate each language into it's own native form, so that the output would be

```
English Deutsch Nederlands
```

Making it easier for people to find on the page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While @mongoose_za's answer is thorough and useful, it answers a different question and not the one posed.

The real answer is simply to change your list of languages in settings to include those native forms as such:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', u'Deutsch'),
    ('en', u'English'),
    ('nl', u'Nederlands'),
    ('es', u'Español'),
    ('fr', u'français'),
    ('jp', u'日本語'),
)
```

I've added a couple to make it more obvious what we're doing.

Since you wish to always display the languages in their native way, there's no need to translate them, thus, there's no need for the ugettext() wrappers.  You want to make sure that the first line in your settings file is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

To ensure everything is interpreted correctly by Python.

An excellent source for this exercise is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Answer (score 5):

I think it's just the list of languages that need to be translated. Then your above snippet should be fine as is.
In your settings where you list your language it should look something like this:

```
ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', ugettext('German')),
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('nl', ugettext('Dutch')),
    )
```

Because then you would setup the translated strings in your locales files which should be translated on the template with the code you have.

My change language looks like this:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans 'Change language' %}
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" style="display: inline;">{% csrf_token %}
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <select name="language" onchange="javascript:form.submit()">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                <option value="{{ lang.0 }}"{% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE lang.0 %} selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think that this solves the problem. When you translate the languages in the LANGUAGES setting, it means that you would display all languages in the currently active language. OP does not want this. He wants to display the language always in their native spelling.

Comment: Hi, in my admin page. i see the select, but no options... why `LANGUAGES` is empty for me ?

Answer (score 0):

mkoistinen's answer is a nice and simple solution. However that shuts you down from using those language names in any another language, should you ever need to.

Another solution would be to fix mongoose_za's answer by using the `language` template tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates) to switch to each language for each `<a>`.